Firebase firestore rules do not take name from token from flutter app
Once user singup I change the firebase users display name to nickname provided by user and create a doc in that name. But when I try to update the doument it thorws code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions.. If I remove the request.auth.name == userId from the rule it works fine. User display name is saved on firebase becuase when I log out and log back in I get the same user display name.
How to resolve this issue?
my rule
  allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.name == userId;
  allow delete: if false;
  allow read,create: if request.auth != null;

After updating I revalidate the token using getIdToken
 await user.updateDisplayName(username);
 var token = await user.getIdToken(true);

The token also contains username.

This is my code to update
  var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("players")
            .doc("meanman");

 await ref.update(map);



Please edit your question and show the code that you're using to perform the update. Besides that, are you sure you're authenticated when you're performing the update operation?

@AlexMamo I have updated the question. Yes, user is authenticated. I tried creating a new account and logout and login as well. Still the rule throws this error.

What are the values of  FirebaseConstants.collectionPlayers and name.toLowerCase()? Please also edit your question and add a screenshot of your database.

@AlexMamo done!, I can read the data and only issue is on update rule having this segment "request.auth.name == userId". If I remove it, all work fine.

Are you sure you're authenticated when you're performing the update operation?

yes, I have to read the data before the update. Read works. Also if I remove request.auth.name == userId and leave if request.auth != null update works as well.

According to your comment:

Also if I remove request.auth.name == userId and leave if request.auth != null update works as well.

I suspect that you need to use:
request.auth.uid == userId
//           

Because the name in the auth object is different than the uid which is generated by Firebase.

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth name can be used if set. it is set when I inspect the token. I cant change to uid now becuase app is released and there is data in the database.

userid in my case is username. so changing to uid is wrong.
